# How to make scrollable image (vertical) and can pinch to zoom images

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a list of images that I can scroll through vertically and can zoom the image. I can scroll the images but I can't zoom the images.

```
class ScrollVertical extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
  _ScrollVerticalState createState() => _ScrollVerticalState();
}

class _ScrollVerticalState extends State<ScrollVertical>  {
  double _scale = 1.0;
  double _previousScale = 1.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Column Layout"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
```

Here where the list of images can be scroll

```
      body: SingleChildScrollView(   //to scroll images
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
            ),
          InteractiveViewer(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            minScale: 1,
            maxScale: 4,
            child: Image.asset("assets/imgs/chalkboard.png"), // first image
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
          ),
```

This will be followed by the next images.

```
           
          InteractiveViewer(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            minScale: 1,
            maxScale: 4,
            child: Image.asset("assets/imgs/Gojo.png"),    //second image
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
            ),

          InteractiveViewer(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            minScale: 1,
            maxScale: 4,
            child: Image.asset("assets/imgs/Equations.png"),    third image
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
            ),
          ]
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I use `InteractiveViewer` to implement pinch to zoom but it not work. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';

> install command: flutter pub add photo_view

`https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view/install`

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(   //to scroll images
                       child: Column(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Padding(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                           ),
           PhotoView(
                 imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/imgs/chalkboard.png"),
               )
                      
                         Padding(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                         ),
        PhotoView(
                 imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/imgs/Gojo.png"),
               )
         Padding(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                         ),
        PhotoView(
                 imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/imgs/Equations.png"),
               )
       Padding(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30),
                         ),
```

Comment: I use this, but there is an error say `The method 'PhotoView' isn't defined for the type '_ScrollVerticalState'.` and it not display the images

Answer (score 0):

you can use `photo_view` package from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/), [link](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view)

> install command: `flutter pub add photo_view`

```
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
.
.
.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: PhotoView(
      imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/large-image.jpg"),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ScrollBar](https://www.google.com/search?q=scroll%20in%20vertical%20in%20flutter&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN914IN914&sxsrf=AOaemvKLkWAX6Eg0I0JbwmAgWFtt9kaRYQ%3A1641553714908&ei=Mh_YYerbNoTl2roP46mS8Ac&ved=0ahUKEwjqvLmQwJ_1AhWEslYBHeOUBH4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=scroll%20in%20vertical%20in%20flutter&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFgAYABoAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQA&sclient=gws-wiz#kpvalbx=_OB_YYcrdGMLe2roPxuqt-Ac18)

To move vertical use scrollbar, put image in container and wrap with  photoview and it should wrap with ScrollBar

```
ScrollBar(container(photoview("Image")))
```